# How to batch delete in Knex?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, batch-delete

I'd like to perform batch deletion using knex.js. We have batchInsert as an API method , but nothing as far as batchDelete is concerned.

I tried async iteration and delete each row separately. But it's not efficient ,because we have lot of server to DB calls. I'm looking into a possibility, if DB have 100 records the batch of 25 records should be delete every time

Any ideas welcome!!

Comment: What do you mean by batch delete? what would be the sql statement?

Comment: delete from table1 where id=%id%. I've millions of record to delete every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given ids of the items that you need to delete, you can use the `In` SQL statement.

It should look like:

```sql
Delete from tableName Where id In (1,2,3,45,636,52);
```

In order to build this query using `knex`

```
db('tableName')
  .delete()
  .whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 45, 636, 52]);
```

Comment: I have the same logic. But I'm looking for a possibility to delete id in parallel mode.

Comment: How do u know that the db engine is not doing it in parallel?

Comment: I'm looking into a possibility, if DB have 100 records the batch of 25 records should be delete every time.

Comment: so, given a full list of ids to delete, chunk it into 25 items (can be done with lodash.chunk),  iterate over it, and for each invoke the whereIn that will contain 25 ids...

Comment: QQ: Is it possible to chunk the query for `db('tableName')
  .delete()
  .whereIn('id', query);`

Comment: What do you mean by "to chunk the query for"?